# I can hear myself through my headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

I bought a wireless headset yesterday, and I tested it on Windows, it worked alright. Then I went to Linux, connected the headset, and noticed I could hear myself. I've tried looking at `alsamixer` to see what could be disabled, but nothing seems to change, and in `pavucontrol` it all seems to be alright too.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Try to mute the microphone.

Comment: Muting the mic isn't the best solution, especially when planning to talk to people. Granted, I stop hearing myself, but I'd like other people to hear me without going crazy.

Comment: Actually, muting the mic on Ubuntu still makes me hear the echo, yet muting the mic on the headset itself stops the echo.

Comment: You may have selected a duplex profile. http://askubuntu.com/questions/94854/how-do-i-turn-off-audio-echo-from-microphone-to-local-speakers - pavucontrol gives us access to this feature: http://askubuntu.com/a/297911/3940

Comment: I've selected Analog Stereo Output + Analog Mono Input, not Duplex.

Comment: Just an FYI that some headsets (especially Turtle Beach) have the mic hard-wired to the headset speakers as a *feature* so that you know when your mic is hot/on.  I've experienced the level feedback of this changing (becoming louder/softer) when connecting to different devices.

Comment: @earthmeLon I did some research on it, it turns out you are right. It's called sidetone, and it can be turned off holding a button for 2 seconds. It's kinda cryptic though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some headsets (especially Turtle Beach) have the mic hard-wired to the headset speakers as a feature so that you know when your mic is hot/on. I've experienced the level feedback of this changing (becoming louder/softer) when connecting to different devices.

It's been noted that this is called **sidetone**.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/469366/how-do-i-enable-microphone-sidetone-in-ubuntu/733328#733328

Answer (score 0):

hearing yourself through headphones means you don't get louder and louder and annoy everyone else within earshot. It was an early feature on original telephones where they used a twin T transformer (hw circuit) to provide the feed back.